# With IndexedDB, is it possible to create an object store in the onsuccess event of the window.indexedDB.open?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I'm building an application where I want to attempt to re-pull data from the database each time the page loads. If there isn't a network connection, then I'll use the data stored in IndexedDB.

To do this, I thought it would make sense to clear our my existing objectstores in the onsuccess event of the window.indexedDB.open function, then recreate with new data. Something like this:

```
var request = window.indexedDB.open("offlineInspections",1);
        
request.onsuccess = function(event){    
    db = request.result;
    //Check if connected to network
    //If yes, pull new data
    // TODO (will use AJAX to make a server call)
    
    //Check if current data exists
    //If yes, delete
    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("user")){
        db.deleteObjectStore("user");
    }
        
    //Load new data
    var userStore = db.createObjectStore("user",{keyPath: "id"}); //Throws error
    var transaction = event.target.transaction;
    
    transaction.oncomplete = function(event){
        console.log('New user store created');
    }
}
```

When I try to run this, I get the following error on the line noted above:

> Uncaught DOMException: A mutation operation was attempted on a database that did not allow mutations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change the object stores and indices of a database from within the onupgradeneeded event handler function, which operates within the context of an version change read write transaction.

The onupgradeneeded event handler is a different handler than the successful open request event handler. The successful open event handler is not permitted to make changes to the object stores or indices. The success event only happens after the upgrade transaction completes. By that point in time you are attempting a mutation operation (a command to create/delete an object store) on a database that did not allow mutations (outside of the context of a version change transaction).

The solution is to use the onupgradeneeded handler:

```js
var request = indexedDb.open(...);

request.onupgradeneeded = function(event) {
  // do database changes here, e.g.
  var db = event.target.result;
  db.createObjectStore(...);
};

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
  // do database reads/writes here
  // you cannot use createObjectStore here
};
```